# Bounding $U_n = \int_0^1(1-x)^n\exp(2x)\,dx$

Tags: sequences-and-series, integration

Suppose the sequence $(U)_{n\ge 1}$ defined by $U_n = \int_0^1(1-x)^n\exp(2x)\,dx$.

How can I prove that:

- $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}\setminus{0} \quad \frac{1}{n+1}\le U_n\le \frac{\exp(2)}{n+1}$.
- $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}\setminus{0} \quad2U_{n+1}=(n+1)U_n-1$ and conclude the limit.

I tried to use Induction and derivative but I couldn't bound the first inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

1) Note that $1\leq\exp(2x)\leq\exp(2)$ for $x\in[0,1]$. Multiply this inequality by $(1-x)^n$ and then integrate that inequality over $[0,1]$.

2) Use integration by parts. Set $u=(1-x)^{n+1}$ and $dv=\exp(2x)dx$

Answer (score 0):

Hints for the first part: Replace the exponential function in the integrand by its upper and lower bounds.

Hint for the second part: Smells like a partial integration.